# perl DBI : ressource temporarily unavailable

Tags: perl, dbi

I would like to parse a DB using a first request to retrieve a problem list, then retrieve all the fields in my database foreach item included in the problem.

CachéDB is a proprietary database I cannot understand why my company bother to use.  The boss said : it is quick, it is object oriented. We have to use it.

```
 #! /usr/bin/perl
 use DBI;
 # my DB is a cache DBI 
 (...)
 $connStr = sprintf(join(';','DRIVER=libcacheodbc.so;SERVER=%s;PORT=%s'
                            ,'DATABASE=%s;PROTOCOL=TCP;UID=%s;PWD=%s'
                            ,'STATIC CURSORS=0;'
                        )
                   ,'127.0.0.1', ... , $usr, $pass
                   );
 my $dbh  = DBI->connect( $connStr , $user , $pass) or die $! ; 
 my $req1 = $dbh->prepare("Select ip, max(date) as maxdate 
                            from dbtable 
                            group by ip having count(*) > 1");
 # TODO: Purge not requested records from the DB.
 my $req2 = $dbh->prepare("select * 
                            from dbtable 
                            where ip = ? and date < ?");
 my $ans1 = $req1->execute() or die $! ;
 while(defined (my $problem_ip = $ans1->fecthrow_hashref())) {
      my  $ans2 = $req2->execute( $problem_ip->{'ip'}
                                , $problem_ip->{'maxdate'}
                                );
      # $ans2 eq '0E0'
      # $! eq 'Ressource temporarily unavailable'

      use Data::Dumper; 
      print Dumper $ans2->fetchall_hashref() ;
      # will fails : Not a reference.

      ... 
      # use stuff
 }
```

Requests (`$req1` && `$req2`) seem to works separately (when process has stopped).

How can I handle  cacheDB to simultaneously retrieve datas from several requests?

Comment: Use a separate connection for each request.

Comment: Using a second connection, connect function called twice (same user, same everything) does not seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Which DBD module are you using here? What does your `$connStr` variable contain?

Comment: I think some confusion has been caused by you not using standard names for DBI-related variables. Your `$conn` variable is more usually called `$dbh` (and is created with `my $dbh = DBI->connect(...)` not the `new DBI(...)` which you use here).

Comment: Your `$req1` and `$req2` variables are statement handles and would more commonly be called `$sth_foo` and `$sth_bar` (where "foo" and "bar" would be replaced by short descriptions of the statements in question).

Comment: dbi version is 1.609.

Comment: But most confusing to me are your `$ans1` and `$ans2` variables. They are both created from the return values from a call to `execute()`. But `execute()` returns a scalar value (either a true/false flag or the number of rows updated). It never returns an object, but you're trying to call methods on those variables as though they are statement handles. I have no idea how `$ans1->fecthrow_hashref()` could ever work (but the typo in the method name makes me suspicious of all of your code!)

Comment: Version 1.609 was released ten years ago. Why are you using such old software?

Comment: Note that $! does NOT contain the DBI error, so you may be seeing spurious error messages. You need to use $DBI::errstr instead.

Comment: `$connStr` has been detailled.

Comment: @MUYBelgium: `$connStr` should start "dbi:XXXX", where "XXXX" is the name of the database driver module you are using.

Comment: `DBI->connect` doesn't set `$!` (and the same goes for `$sth->execute`). That's set by system calls. `DBI->connect` sets `DBI->errstr`. /// By the way, instead of checking for errors throughout your code, you can use use `DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $passwd, { RaiseError=>1, PrintError=>0 })` to get an exception on error.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I worked with Interystem Cache, they provide 'Intersys::PERLBIND' library which you have to build on your local machine.

https://cedocs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GBPL_intro

How to use -
https://cedocs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GBPL_using_basics

Check with your organization, they should have this module or since your organization is using Intersyscache you can touch base with there DB support, that how I get this thing working.

P.s. CachéDB is a proprietary database I cannot understand why my company bother to use. The boss said : it is quick, it is object oriented  --> I feel you, same argument everywhere